# Angular node_modules/@types Error while (Serve Build Issue)

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-package-format

After **npm install,** when I try to '**ng build**' the following error occurs:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(713,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6/base.d.ts(13,21): error TS2727: Cannot find lib definition for 'esnext.bigint'. Did you mean 'esnext.intl'?
node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(119,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt64Array'.
node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(120,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigUint64Array'.
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install`? You need to add some background here, and what you've tried, not just the error you're getting.

Comment: I had done npm install, then after make a build, its an build time error, due to type script version. @christiandev

Comment: I had solve my problem its due to typescript version 3.1.6, by changing the version of typescript its has been solved @christiandev

Comment: To which version you have promoted or demoted your typescript version?

Comment: Try To update the typescript version >=3.2.1 @BalrajAllam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try installing typescript version as -
npm install typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.3"

Comment: This did not solve my issue. I'm using "typescript" 3.9.3 and even put it in "resolutions" to test as well.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: try changing the typescript version to 3.2.4 it did work for me.

Comment: confirmed version 3.2.4 removes the bigint issue

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once! I have been working on this issue for two days now. The build works locally, but when I try and build in a docker image it fails with this error. I changed the version as mentioned by @IanPreglo and it worked immediately. TypeScript 3.2.4 is definitely the fix! Thank you!